# how to get all traceroute ip node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ping, traceroute

I need to get all traceroute ip information in node js. I have used `npm install traceroute`  lib, but have such a problem with lib js file.

```
c:\Users\Frank\WebstormProjects\Whois.uz\server\node_modules\traceroute\traceroute.js:114
    lines.splice(0,i);
                ReferenceError: i is not defined
at Object.internals.Traceroute.trace.internals.parseOutput (c:\Users\Frank\WebstormProjects\Whois.uz\server\node_modules\traceroute\traceroute.js:114:24)
at c:\Users\Frank\WebstormProjects\Whois.uz\server\node_modules\traceroute\traceroute.js:35:39
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:193:7)
at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)
```

What is the best way to get it? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code first with a real problem.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/traceroute      I'm using this, but it's not working, I want to know the best and easy way to get this information in node js

Comment: What is not working? What have you tried? Do you get any errors? Is your programm syntax correct? etc.

Comment: Have you tried to make a traceroute to desired target over the command shell of your OS? Is that working?

Comment: lines.splice(0,i);     ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at Object.internals.Traceroute.trace.internals.parseOutput (c:\Users\Frank\WebstormProjects\Whois.uz\server\node_modules\traceroute\traceroute.js:114:24)
    at c:\Users\Frank\WebstormProjects\Whois.uz\server\node_modules\traceroute\traceroute.js:35:39
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:193:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
   I'm getting this error

Comment: Post this in your question!!!!

Comment: possibly related to this? https://github.com/jaw187/node-traceroute/issues/8